# Hatcher: Decomposition of space into X path components $\{X_\alpha\}$ gives isomorphism $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus H_n(X_\alpha)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is not a duplicate. Other answers to this question used language of category theory, which I am not familiar to (I don't know what a functor is etc...)

Proposition 2.6 in Hatcher's book, p109, says:

> Corresponding to the decomposition of a space $X$ into its
>   pathcomponents $X_\alpha$, there is an isomorphism of $H_n(X)$ with
>   the direct sum $\bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha)$.

Proof: Since a singular simplex always has path-connected image, $C_n(X)$ splits as the direct sum of its subgroups $C_n(X_\alpha)$. The boundary maps $\partial_n$ preserve this direct sum decomposition, taking $C_n(X_\alpha)$ to $C_{n-1}(X_{\alpha})$, so $\operatorname{Ker} \partial_n$ and $\operatorname{Im} \partial_{n+1}$ split similarly as direct sums, hence the homology groups also split, $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus H_n(X_\alpha)$. $\quad \square$

I managed to show that $C_n(X) \cong \bigoplus C_n(X_\alpha)$ but I'm stuck from there.

What does "The boundary maps $\partial_n$ preserve this direct sum decomposition, taking $C_n(X_\alpha)$ to $C_{n-1}(X_{\alpha})$" even mean? Do I have to prove that

$$\partial_n(C_n(X)) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha \partial_n(C_n(X_\alpha))$$?

If so, how do I show this?

Also,  how does "$\operatorname{Ker} \partial_n$ and $\operatorname{Im} \partial_{n+1}$ split similarly as direct sums" then follow and why does this even imply that the homology groups split as direct sums?

Comment: The boundary maps preserve the direct sums means exactly what you wrote and even more - that $\partial_n C_n(X_\alpha)$ is in $C_{n-1}(X_\alpha)$ (not in any of the other $C_{n-1}(X_\beta)$'s.  This gives the splitting of the kernel and images almost directly.

Comment: And how can I prove this? If you would just hint me the right isomorphism, this would already give me a good start!

Comment: It's really just from the definition.  If you're using singular singular homology, you can see that since a simplex is path connected, its image is also path connected (under a continuous map).  Now, apply this to the simplices that appear in the definition of the boundary map.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how that gives me an isomorphism. My definition is indeed $\partial_n(\sigma) = \sum_i (-1)^i \sigma\vert{[v_0, \dots, \hat{v_i}, \dots, v_n]}$ where $\sigma$ is an $n$-simplex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have any subspace $X' \subset X$, then $C_n(X')$ canonically embeds as a subgroup of $C_n(X)$:

Let $j : X' \to X$ denote inclusion, then we define $C_n(j) : C_n(X') \to C_n(X)$ by  $C_n(j)(\sigma) = j \circ \sigma$ on the generators $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X'$. This is obviuosly an embedding of free abelian groups. Consider the boundaries $\partial_n^{X'} : C_{n+1}(X') \to C_n(X')$ and $\partial_n^{X} : C_{n+1}(X) \to C_n(X)$. Clearly we have $C_n(j) \circ \partial_n^{X'} = \partial_n^{X} \circ C_{n+1}(j)$.

The isomorphism $\phi_n : \bigoplus C_n(X_\alpha) \to C_n(X)$ has therefore the property
$$\phi_n \circ \bigoplus \partial_n^{X_\alpha} = \partial_n^{X} \circ \phi_{n+1} .$$
This is the meaning of "The boundary maps preserve this direct sum decomposition".

Thus
$$H_n(X) = \ker(\partial_{n-1}^X)/\text{im}(\partial_n^X) \approx \ker \left(\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha} \right) / \text{im} \left(\bigoplus \partial_n^{X_\alpha} \right) \\ \approx \left(\bigoplus \ker (\partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha}) \right) /  \left(\bigoplus \text{im}(\partial_n^{X_\alpha} )\right) \approx \bigoplus \ker (\partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha}) / \text{im}(\partial_n^{X_\alpha} ) = \bigoplus H_n(X_\alpha).$$

**Edited:**

Concerning the first isomorphism in the above chain:

Let $a \in C_n(X)$. Then $a \in \ker(\partial^X_{n−1})$ iff $\partial^X_{n−1}(a)=0$ iff $(\phi_{n−1} \circ \bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha} \circ \phi_n^{-1})(a)=0$ iff $\bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha} (\phi_n^{-1}(a))=0$ iff $\phi_n^{-1}(a) \in \ker(\bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha})$ iff $a \in \phi_n(\ker(\partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha}))$, i.e. we have $\ker(\partial^X_{n−1})=\phi_n(\ker(\bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha}))$. Similarly $\text{im}(\partial^X_{n−1})=\phi_n(\text{im}(\bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha}))$. Hence
$$\ker(\partial_{n-1}^X)/\text{im}(\partial_n^X) = \phi_n(\ker(\bigoplus\partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha})) / \phi_n(\text{im}(\bigoplus \partial_{n−1}^{X_\alpha})) \approx \ker \left(\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha} \right) / \text{im} \left(\bigoplus \partial_n^{X_\alpha} \right) $$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you further explain how this implies that $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha)$?

Comment: See  my edit ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to make sure I get it!

Comment: I managed to understand the largest part of the answer, but why exactly does $C_n(j) \circ \partial_n^{X'} = \partial_n^X \circ C_{n+1}(j)$. A calculation shows me that I should be able to interchange a function composition and a formal sum but I'm not sure why this is allowed. Care to explain? Thanks!

Comment: @user745578 This is just a special case of assigning to a map $f : X \to Y$ induced homomorphisms $C_n(f) = f_\# :C_n(X) \to C_n(Y)$, i.e. a *chain map* $C_*(f) : C_*(X) \to C_*(Y)$.  See Hatcher p. 110/111.

Comment: Hi again. I have a follow up question. Could you sketch how $\phi_n \circ  \bigoplus \partial_n^{X_\alpha}= \partial_n^X \circ \phi_{n+1}$ implies the first isomorphism in your chain of isomorphisms?

Comment: @user745578 Let $a  \in C_n(X)$. Then $a \in \ker(\partial_{n-1}^{X})$ iff $\partial_n^{X}(a) = 0$ iff $(\phi_{n-1} \circ \bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha} \circ \phi_n^{-1})(a) = 0$ iff $\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha}(\phi_n^{-1}(a)) = 0$ iff $\phi_n^{-1}(a) \in \ker(\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha})$ iff $a \in \phi_n(\ker(\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha}))$, i.e. we have $\ker(\partial_{n-1}^{X}) = \phi_n(\ker(\bigoplus \partial_{n-1}^{X_\alpha}))$. Similarly $\text{im}(\partial_n^{X_\alpha}) = \phi_n(\text{im}(\bigoplus \partial_n^{X_\alpha}))$. The desired equation follows.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and comments helped me very much so I decided to start a bounty to reward  you extra. I can award this tomorrow. Have a great day/night!

Comment: I added my comment to my answer.

Comment: Since you did not seem to explicitly use the fact that $X_\alpha$ are path connected, would it be safe to conclude that, in singular homology, it is always the case that $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus H_n(X_\alpha)$ for any disjoint set of $X_\alpha$ such that $\cup_\alpha X_\alpha = X$? I'm asking because it is also used in Corollary 2.25. in Hatcher's book, where it is not clear that $X_\alpha$ are path connected.

Comment: @Anon All we need to know is that the image of each singular simplex $\sigma : \Delta^n  \to X$ is contained in some $X_\alpha$. Thus it works if the $X_\alpha$ are the path-components of $X$. It also works if we take the $X_\alpha$ to be the connected components of $X$ (note that each connected component is the union of suitable path-components). Another case is that that $X = \bigcup X_\alpha$ with pairwise disjoint open $X_\alpha$. If we drop the assumption "open", it is in general not true ($[0,1] = (0,1) \cup \{0,1\}$; now compute $H_0$).

Comment: Hatcher's Corollary 2.25 does not fit into this pattern. The $X_\alpha$ are not pairwise disjoint. It is a consequence of Proposition 2.22 which deals with good pairs.