# Homology translates path component decomposition to direct sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I want to show that for a space $X$ we have $H_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_n(X_i)$ where $X=\coprod_{i \in I}X_i$ is a decomposition into path components. I tried to approach it the following way.

$(1)$ For chain complexes $(C^i_{\bullet}, \partial^i_{\bullet})_{i \in I}$ we have that $H_n \left(\bigoplus_i C_{\bullet}^i\right) \cong \bigoplus_i H_n(C_{\bullet}^i)$

Proof. There is an exact sequence
$$0 \to \text{im}(\partial_{n+1}^i) \to \ker(\partial_n^i) \to H_n(X_i) \to 0$$ for every $i$ and $n$, given by the inclusion and projection. Since the direct sum is exact, this gives the exact sequence
$$0 \to \bigoplus_i \text{im}(\partial^i_{n+1}) \to \bigoplus_i \ker(\partial^i_n) \to \bigoplus_i H_n(X_i) \to 0.$$

At this point I was trying to find some arguments why this sequence splits but couldn't find any. Thats why I proceeded as follows. We know that the image and kernel commutes with direct sums and thus we get that $$\ker\left(\bigoplus_i \partial_n^i \right)/\text{im}\left(\bigoplus_i \partial_{n+1}^i\right) \cong \bigoplus_i \ker(\partial_n)/\text{im}(\partial_{n+1})= \bigoplus_i H_n(C_{\bullet}^i)$$ What is missing is that $H_n\left(\bigoplus_i C_{\bullet}^i\right) \cong \ker\left(\bigoplus_i \partial_n^i \right)/\text{im}\left(\bigoplus_i \partial_{n+1}^i\right)$ but I think this just follows by definition of the direct sum of complexes.

$(2)$ We have $H_n \left(\coprod_i X_i \right) \cong H_n(\bigoplus C_{\bullet}^i)$. I don't really know how to show this. I thought that one can perhaps show that the respective complexes are isomorphic but this seems to be laborious.

If $(1)$ and $(2)$ are shown to be true, one can conclude that $$H_n\left(\coprod_i X_i \right) \cong H_n\left(\bigoplus_i C_{\bullet}^i\right) \cong \bigoplus_i H_n\left(C_{\bullet}^i\right)=\bigoplus_i H_n(X_i).$$

Furthermore I wondered whether there is actually an equality of $\ker(\bigoplus_i \partial_n^i)$ and $\bigoplus_i \ker(\partial_n^i)$ and analogously for the image, rather than them "only" being isomorphic.

Could you tell me if what I did so far is correct and help me fill in the gaps? Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528349.

Comment: you can find any introduction to algebraic toopology textbook, they will explain detaily.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks. Could you explain what the $\phi_n$ is? Is it the direct sum of the $C_n(j_{\alpha})$?

Comment: @user103178981 Yes. If you think in terms of generators of the free abelian groups of singular $n$-chains, you will see that each generator $\sigma \in C_n(X)$ (which is a map $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X$) belongs to exactly one $C_n(X_\alpha)$. This defines $\phi_n$ on the generators of $\bigoplus C_n(X_\alpha)$.